# Python pandas: create a dataframe of dates from existing columns

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column for years and one for months. How can I create a new date column based on these two (I can assume day = 15).

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime  

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['year'] = np.arange(2000,2010)

df['mydate']= datetime.date( df['year'].apply(lambda x: int(x)) , 1 , 1)
```

but I get this error message:

> ```
> df['mydate']= datetime.date( df['year'].apply(lambda x: int(x)) , 1 , 1)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
> ```
>
> line 77, in wrapper
>       "cannot convert the series to {0}".format(str(converter))) TypeError: cannot convert the series to

which I don't understand because I explictly convert x to int.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build another column based on the existing columns by using `df.apply(fnc, axis=1)`.

In your case this becomes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['year'] = np.arange(2000,2010)
df['month'] = 6

df['date_time']= df.apply(lambda row :
                          datetime.date(row.year,row.month,15), 
                          axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Was the error with my code because datetime.date works on a single row, and with functions working on rows one at a time I hvae to do apply( fun() ) rather than fun ( apply() ) ?

Comment: You were supplying a `DataFrame` as an argument to `datetime.date()`, which doesn't make sense. As `date()` doesn't know what to do with it, it apparently tries to convert it to an int. In my example you call `datetime` on three integers. I.e. the `lambda` receives a `row` (a `Series`) as input, and outputs a `date` object, which is then aggregated by `df.apply` to a `Series` which is returned.